# Change price by adding product to cart in Prestashop

Tags: php, ajax, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I've created a little Prestashop module. With this module you can customize a product.

When adding the product to the cart with this code

```
<a class="exclusive ajax_add_to_cart_button" rel="ajax_id_product_{$product.id_product}" 
href="{$link->getPageLink('cart')}?qty=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product}&amp;
token={$static_token}&amp;add" title="{l s='Add to cart' mod='folienplotter'}">
{l s='Add to cart' mod='folienplotter'}</a>
```

the calculated price should be passed to the product. I don't know how to manage this.

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: What do you mean with calculated price?? What do you mean witn "passed" to product??

Comment: With the module you can customize a product. Then the module generates a price. If you press the "Add to cart" button, the product with the calculated price should be added to the cart.

Comment: You can't change product price. If you do that you will have problems later confirming order. I recommend you that do no touch product price calculation functions because are very complex. Good luck.

Comment: Do you have an other solution?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of "passing" the price to the product in your module when adding the product, you can add a SpecificPrice with the current id_cart:

```
$specific_price = new SpecificPrice();
$specific_price->id_product = (int)$id_product; // choosen product id
$specific_price->id_product_attribute = (int)$id_product_attribute; // optional or set to 0
$specific_price->id_cart = (int)$current_id_cart;
$specific_price->from_quantity = 1;
$specific_price->price = $new_price_without_tax;
$specific_price->reduction_type = 'amount';
$specific_price->reduction_tax = 1;
$specific_price->reduction = 0;
$specific_price->from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$specific_price->to = "0000-00-00 00:00:00"; // or set date x days from now
$specific_price->add();
```

Then Prestashop should make the calculations.

Comment: Like the idea of this. The only problem with this is, that If a customer choose to put another product of the same product in cart with a different customization, it will override the price of the first product added to cart.

Comment: true. there is no id_costumization in specific_price. but there is no id_costumization in cart. can you have 2 products with same id_product and same id_product_attribute with different customization?

Comment: It's sad Prestashop doesn't have a way to update cart pricing. This solution just creates a price rule for that cart only. more than 1 item with the same sku in the cart will change price. I am hoping for a better solution. For now, this looks to be the only way to do it without editing core code.